# Why is [A-Za-z0-9 ]* matching the space between non-ASCII letters in sed?

Tags: sed

I am trying to mark all of the Latin-alphabet components in a file, e.g.:

```
This is English. 这是中文。 This is more English.
```

This would be marked like this:

```
\english{This is English.} 这是中文。 \english{This is more English.}
```

I have tried to use `sed` to mark the words:

```
sed 's/[A-Za-z0-9 ]*/\\english{&}/g' file
```

After running this, it is mostly correct, however, it is also placing the mark between all of the Chinese characters, e.g.:

```
\english{This is English.} 这\english{}是\english{}中\english{}文\english{}。 \english{This is more English.}
```

It is also marking places which are just a space, but which do not need the mark, e.g.:

```
这是中文。 这也是中文。
```

This becomes:

```
这是中文。\english{ }这也是中文。
```

How can I modify this `sed` script such that it does not mark spaces between characters as `\english{}` and does not place any `\english{ }`'s in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
LC_ALL="POSIX" sed -r 's/[^\o200-\o377]+/\\english{&}/g' file.txt
```

Results:

```
\english{This is English. }这是中文。\english{ This is more English.}
```

Answer (score 2):

The marks between characters are caused by the `*` which means "zero or more". If you mean "one or more", use `\+` instead of `*`.

If you do not want to match a single space, you can use e.g.

```
sed 's/[A-za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*/\\english{&}/g'
```

which means there must be at least one non-space character.

Answer (score 1):

`[A-Za-z0-9 ]*` essentially means match any Latin letter, Arabic number, and the whitespace.

You want something like `([A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9 ,.!?']*)`

There are nice RegExp experimentation tools like [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression means: Match any alphanumeric character and any space. Thus spaces between Chinese text is also matched.

Try this one:

```
 's/[A-Za-z0-9]* */\\english{&}/g' file
```

Meaning match any alphanumeric character followed by zero or more spaces.